# "java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind" when I start Jetty in eclipse mars

Tags: java, spring, gradle, jetty

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':project-web:jettyRun'.

  > java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.BindException: Address alrea
  >   dy in use: JVM_Bind
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
  option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Comment: Unclear which of this is yours and which is computer output.

Comment: Do you have Jetty already running on that port outside of eclipse?

Comment: Is that considered to be a question?

Comment: What version of Jetty?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt : jetty 7

Comment: @jan.supol : No, i have checked everywhere nothing is running.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:FAILED
>   SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080 FAILED: java.net.BindException:
>   Address already in use

I had the same problem. In my case i tried to run jetty server on windows 8. When i execute mvn jetty:run command had the error on port number 8080. My port no 8080 was running by malware(sysnetwk.exe) after i killed the process(sysnetwk.exe) running on 8080 jetty server started. it works fine now 
If anyone has this problem they can follow below steps

1. you need to find which process running on port no (in my case port no 8080)

   c:\ Windows\system32>netstat -ano | findstr 8080

   TCP      0.0.0.0:8080     LISTENING     6772
2. Kill the process using PID

   c:\ Windows\system32>taskkill /F /pid 6772

   Success: process terminated.

If you can't kill the process using cmd prompt then you can use task manager(`ctrl+shift+esc`) to kill the process

Answer (score 0):

This may be because of other thread already using the JVM debug port.
go to the task manager and kill the javaw.exe and java.exe and try again.

Comment: Then you have other process running on the same port you are attempting to use Jetty on.  Pick a different port for your Jetty instance (or fix the other process to use a different port)

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt : i changed port and try again but same result come :( . i tried 8080 - 8089. when i start jetty instance then some other process use same port.

Comment: I run the netstat cmd to check the what process running on same port but no other process is running.

Comment: @sanjay3722 if you changed your jetty port, then its likely that you are attempting to start 2 connectors on the same port from within Jetty itself.