# Server already in use mistake

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have a problem with running application. As I understand from log something is going wrong with pom.xml. My code is here [github](https://github.com/maksymsereda/BookManagerApplication). Thanks in advance.
My log is:

```
[INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:3.3:run (default-cli) @ BookManger ---
[INFO] Logging to org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
[INFO] configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.9
[INFO] configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.9
[INFO] Relativizing decoration links with respect to project URL: https://github.com/maksymsereda/BookManagerApplication
[INFO] Rendering site with org.apache.maven.skins:maven-default-skin:jar:1.0 skin.
[INFO] Starting Jetty on http://localhost:8080/
[INFO] jetty-6.1.25
[INFO] NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
[INFO] Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
```

When I try to enter the localhost:8080 there is a standart Maven information.
Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.springapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>BookManger</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>BookManger</name>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>
        <hibeArnate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibeArnate.version>
    </properties>

    <url>https://github.com/maksymsereda/BookManagerApplication</url>
    <distributionManagement>
        <site>
            <id>site</id>
            <name>site</name>
            <url>scp://www.yourcompany.com/www/docs/project/</url>
        </site>
    </distributionManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0.CR1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0.CR1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Apache Commons DBCP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--MysQL-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.36</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>BookManger</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
                <version>2.21.0</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I spent all the day to fix it and still nothing. For now I have the following. Thanks for those who helps me
[image]

Comment: Seems port 8080 is already in use. see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33411182/java-net-bindexception-address-already-in-use-jvm-bind-when-i-start-jetty-in

Comment: @user6690200 ok i restart close all programms that used 8080, after that I have the similar mistake (edited log  in my question)

Answer (score 2):

The port `8080` is already in use by a different process. You need to terminate it in order to build the project.

Suppose you use windows:

1. Open cmd.exe and type `netstat -aon | find "8080"` which finds all the processes using the port 8080.
2. Press <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>, click the tab processes and terminate ones according to the found PID numbers. Alternatively type `taskkill /F /pid XXX` to force terminating the process, where `XXX` stands for the PID number from the first step.

Comment: ok did what you propose, and you were right about using the port 8080. But there is still a mistake (editted log in my post). Could you please have a look?

Comment: What mistakes are you talking about? Warnings are not errors and they don't break the build (at 99%). To fix this warning add `maven-project-info-reports-plugin` in the `plugin` element. The second warning fix adding `<url>`.

Comment: Could you look one more time on my post? I did as you told (I hope I  understand it correctly).

Comment: I see your updated log and only [INFO] left. Do you want to get rid of it too? If so, find a way to disable Maven logging. Otherwise, I don't understand your question.

Comment: I want to see my application after I write localhost:8080 in a search line in browser but it is not happend. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: please look at the picture I added above. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `localhost:8080/BookManager`?

Comment: when I write [localhost:8080/BookManager] I have a website with HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /BookManager. Reason:

    NOT_FOUND
Powered by Jetty://